# Calculate Future PHP Date in Specific Format (dd month yyyy hh:mm:ss)

Tags: php, date

Extreme PHP newbie here - I am trying to create a PHP variable that will be "CURRENT DATE + 7 Days"

Something like :

```
date('D-m-y H:i:s', strtotime(DateTime("+7 day"))
```

However, I need it to output in a format like this: "30 November 2015 09:00:00"

Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the different date format codes.

Comment: I think you're looking for `date('j F Y H:i:s', strtotime("+7 day"));`

Comment: Ahh, okay.

So the first part would be "d-F-Y h:i:s".  Any help with adding 7 days to it?

Comment: My second comment should work. I didn't test it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check the manual for valid date formats](http://php.net/date) and change your format string.

You're basically looking for `date('j F Y H:i:s', strtotime("+7 day"))`

Personally, I recommend working with [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) if you're storing this in a variable and working with it, because it becomes more convenient to extract the formatted date from the object at your conveience any time without having to go back through `date` and `strtotime` each time. Also there are numerous other benefits like not losing timezone information during conversion or having to change global timezones that effect the conversion, etc...

### Example

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable; // today's date
echo $date->modify('+7 days')->format('j F Y H:i:s'); // 7 days from today
echo $date->modify('-7 days')->format('j F Y H:i:s'); // 7 days ago
```